# Komodo Edit auto-complete won't find a Python module

Tags: python, komodo, komodoedit

I am using Komodo edit on a Python file on Windows.

When I type `import s` it successfully lists all the importable files starting with s, including one of my modules in one of my directories.

When I type `import t` it lists all the importable files starting with t, EXCLUDING one of my modules in the same directory.

Even though Komodo can't find it, the Python interpreter finds and runs both files fine. It is purely a problem with Komodo's Code Intelligence.

The name of the missing module is 9 lower-case letters (nothing fancy). It doesn't clash with any other modules. It is in the same directory as the module that can be found.

Any suggestions about why one module is found and another isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved itself when I closed Komodo, saving the project, and reopened it.

Sounds like Komodo's internal representation was out-of-date or corrupted.

I'll leave the question here for the next person who stumbles over it.

Comment: You could file a bug here: http://bugs.activestate.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Komodo